# GeoAlchemy get largest area within intersected polygon

Tags: postgis, geoalchemy

I am using the [world borders](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php) dataset to try and perform an intersection based on the buffer of a point. I need to return the country with the largest area within the buffer.

For example, in the diagram below my query should return the United States:

[image]

This query is incorrectly returning Canada:

```py
point = WKTElement('POINT({} {})'.format(*center_point), srid=4326)

q = db.session.query(WorldBorders.iso2, WorldBorders.geom)\
      .filter(func.ST_Intersects(WorldBorders.geom, func.ST_Buffer(point, 1))).first()
```

Do I need to use an aggregate function and group_by?

Comment: I'm not experienced with the syntax in geoalchemy. So I can't give you the complete statement. I would use the size of the intersecting area, to determine the right country. For a sinlge point it should work in standard sql, if you add to the statement "order by ST_Area(ST_Intersection(buffer_point,country_geom)) desc limit 1". So you get just the first row with the greatest intersection. Maybe this helps to right direction.

Comment: you got me on the right track, thanks.

Comment: You‘re welcome. Glad, I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is getting me the expected results:

```py
point = WKTElement('POINT({} {})'.format(*center_point), srid=4326)

q = db.session.query(WorldBorders.iso2, WorldBorders.geom) \
                .order_by(func.ST_Area(func.ST_Intersection(func.ST_Buffer(point, 1), 
                 WorldBorders.geom)).desc()).first()
```